# Spark Tasks reading the data but not writing back

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

We are using the Spark 1.6 version and while running the jobs in Spark-shell,we observed that tasks are reading the data but not writing them back to complete the tasks as shown in below table

```
Address TaskTime TotalTask FailedTask succeededtask Shuffle/read Shuffle/write
   1       0         0         0            0           188KB/707   0.0B/670
```

Spark program is using 5 executors 5 GB of size and 3 cores
Please suggest here

Comment: Enter your code here rather than your environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by increasing the number of tasks for the partitions in cluster settings